# Android Supporting Multiple Screens Not Working

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-manifest, screen

I am trying to specify on AndroidManifest file that my application should only run on tablets larger than 7'' inches size.

I used the following code on the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iscte.dcti.daam.letters4kids"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"
                android:screenDensity="ldpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"
                android:screenDensity="mdpi" />


        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"
                android:screenDensity="hdpi" />


        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"
                android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

.....
```

The problem is that I tested the .APK on a virtual device "Google Nexus 5" that has 5'' inches on GenyMotion, and the .APK succefully installed and launched !

I don't want that! I don't want to be able to install the application on screens smaller than 7'' inches, why is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should do the job (from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps):

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
   <application ... >
    ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```